# Looking for info on an (epicly) failed British Special Forces mission

Tags: military, britain

A couple of years back I read a Wikipedia article about a UK special forces mission. After a series of bad decisions, most of the crew got killed. I would like to be able to give these events as an example for severe tactical mistakes. However, I do not remember the details of the actual mission.

I seem to recall that the mission went something along these lines:

1. Helicopter insertion.
2. Radio turns out not to work, as no one checked the equipment before departure.
3. First bad decision: do not take motor vehicles, but proceed on foot, despite very heavy equipment(~100 kg per person).
4. Encounter with a shepherd. Overreaction.
5. Encounter with a bulldozer. Overreaction.

After the last incident they are spotted and begin to flee the country. However, the group separates into two separate groups, and I think only two men survive. I believe there is also a book that was written by one of the survivors.

Does anyone know where I can find information on this mission or perhaps the name of the survivor(s) and the book that was written as a result?

Comment: An interesting puzzle, but why are you asking? If you read it online somewhere, I'd like to see the link.

Comment: This would be a great question for a new SE forum called Militaria. https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/99463/militaria

Answer (score 13, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bravo_Two_Zero

A British SAS mission during the First Gulf War and involved:

- Insertion by Helicopter
- Malfunctioning Radios
- Discovery by a Shepherd
- Encounter with a bulldozer
- All but one member killed or captured by enemy

The wiki page lists quite a few details regarding the mission and also gives details on multiple books written on the topic.

Comment: I just read a book on this, but I couldn't remember the name! Great answer by the way.